# Getting null pointer exception In FILE class

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource(filePath + "/createFile.xml").toURI());
```

I get an error of `java.lang.NullPointerException` in above line. Here `filePath` is string variable in which I have set my directory path from where I want to read file.

Comment: Why don't you write the code simply just like this: `new File(filePath+"/createFile.xml");`?

Comment: @ntalbs You have to use getResource if you want to load a file from a jar. For normal files your way is much cleaner.

Comment: I have try like "new File(filePath+"/createFile.xml");" and It's read content successfully, but when I pass this data, I got same errorr in last line of below code.                           File file1 = new File(filePath + "\\createFile.xml");                    Container container = importController.importFile(file1);           container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDefault.DIRECTED);

Answer (score 1):

`Class.getResource()` will return `null` when the resource was not found. You always should test for that before using it.